# Core Plot 1.2 - CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions, axis sometimes not show last label

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot, axis-labels

i've a strange problem with my coreplot graph. 
I have six y axis, and all of them have the policy "CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions".
The graph can be scrolled and the labels on axis was correctly updated.
But sometimes, when i try to scroll the graph down, the last label of a particular axis disappears.

This is the code for create the axis and relative plots, plotspace:

```
CPTXYAxis *A_Axis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] ;
A_Axis.coordinate                  = CPTCoordinateY;
A_Axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal =  CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(_ASpace.yRange.locationDouble);
A_Axis.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
A_Axis.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
A_Axis.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
A_Axis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = MAX_NUMBER_LABEL;
A_Axis.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
A_Axis.labelOffset                 = 3.0;
A_Axis.labelPositionY              = 0.0;
labelTextStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:A_Color.CGColor];
A_Axis.tickDirection               = CPTSignNegative;
A_Axis.labelTextStyle = labelTextStyle;
A_Axis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:0.0];
A_Axis.plotSpace = _ASpace;

CPTXYAxis *B_Axis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] ;
B_Axis.coordinate                  = CPTCoordinateY;
B_Axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(_BSpace.yRange.locationDouble);
B_Axis.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
B_Axis.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
B_Axis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = MAX_NUMBER_LABEL;
B_Axis.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
B_Axis.labelOffset                 = 3.0;
B_Axis.labelPositionY              = 11.0;
labelTextStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:B_Color.CGColor];
B_Axis.tickDirection               = CPTSignNegative;
B_Axis.labelTextStyle = labelTextStyle;
B_Axis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:0.0];
B_Axis.plotSpace = _BSpace;

CPTXYAxis *C_Axis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] ;
C_Axis.coordinate                  = CPTCoordinateY;
C_Axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(_CSpace.yRange.locationDouble);
C_Axis.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
C_Axis.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
C_Axis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = MAX_NUMBER_LABEL;
C_Axis.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
C_Axis.labelOffset                 = 3.0;
C_Axis.labelPositionY              = 22.0;
labelTextStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:C_Color.CGColor];
C_Axis.tickDirection               = CPTSignNegative;
C_Axis.labelTextStyle = labelTextStyle;
C_Axis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:0.0];
C_Axis.plotSpace = _CSpace;

CPTXYAxis *D_Axis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] ;
D_Axis.coordinate                  = CPTCoordinateY;
D_Axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(_DSpace.yRange.locationDouble);
D_Axis.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
D_Axis.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
D_Axis.minorGridLineStyle          = minorGridLineStyle;
D_Axis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = MAX_NUMBER_LABEL;
D_Axis.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
D_Axis.labelOffset                 = 3.0;
D_Axis.labelPositionY              = 0.0;
labelTextStyle.color = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:D_Color.CGColor];
D_Axis.tickDirection               = CPTSignPositive;
D_Axis.labelTextStyle = labelTextStyle;
D_Axis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:1.0];
D_Axis.plotSpace = _DSpace;

CPTXYAxis *E_Axis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] ;
E_Axis.coordinate                  = CPTCoordinateY;
E_Axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(_ESpace.yRange.locationDouble);
E_Axis.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
E_Axis.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
E_Axis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = MAX_NUMBER_LABEL;
E_Axis.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
E_Axis.labelOffset                 = 3.0;
E_Axis.labelPositionY              = 11.0;
labelTextStyle.color               = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:E_Color.CGColor];
E_Axis.tickDirection               = CPTSignPositive;
E_Axis.labelTextStyle              = labelTextStyle;
E_Axis.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:1.0];
E_Axis.plotSpace                   = _ESpace;

CPTXYAxis *F_Axis = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init] ;
F_Axis.coordinate                  = CPTCoordinateY;
F_Axis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(_FSpace.yRange.locationDouble);
F_Axis.labelingPolicy              = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyEqualDivisions;
F_Axis.majorGridLineStyle          = majorGridLineStyle;
F_Axis.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = MAX_NUMBER_LABEL;
F_Axis.minorTicksPerInterval       = 0;
F_Axis.labelOffset                 = 3.0;
F_Axis.labelPositionY              = -11.0;
labelTextStyle.color               = [CPTColor colorWithCGColor:F_Color.CGColor];
F_Axis.tickDirection               = CPTSignPositive;
F_Axis.labelTextStyle              = labelTextStyle;
F_Axis.axisConstraints             = [CPTConstraints constraintWithRelativeOffset:1.0];
F_Axis.plotSpace                   = _FSpace;
```

I've put 3 first axis on the left side (with constraint 0) and the other on the right side of graph.
An example of the problem is shown below where the last green label isn't visible:

http://www.mathnormal.altervista.org/axis.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `labelPositionY` property do?

Comment: I edited a little bit the library function `setLabelOffset`. When the labels are updated i add an y offset to the label point (x,y). However the problem is not there, because i created a project from scratch, with the original CorePlot Library (v. 1.2) and the issue is the same. You can take a look to the video linked below, for more explanation about:[link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACzpSvRaOY8&feature=youtu.be) The y range is `[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(10.0) length:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(50.0)]`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it might be a bug. There could be a rounding error of some sort when using the fixed interval labeling policy. Please report it on the Core Plot [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/list).